Unable to use pexpect.sendline for more than 8000 seconds
There is timeout keyword variable for sendline function in pexpect, I wanted to run my script to wait for response even for almost 2 days, for which I am trying to give timeout=43200 but my child process is showing ERROR: Expect returned EOF after almost 8000 seconds.
I have tried sending empty command hoping to keep the session alive, but it did not work.Is there any way I can keep my child process alive?

please post a [repro].
